How can I insert random rows of one column to another using pandas?`
Thanks in advance for your help and time.
Here's the relevant information:
ASIA
AFGHANISTAN  5,000       JORDAN  1,188        SAUDI ARABIA  619
BAHRAIN  8                KUWAIT  162          

AFRICA
ALGERIA 5,142              ERITREA  211        MOZAMBIQUE  7
ANGOLA  582                ESWATINI  2         NAMIBIA  10

Using pandas, how can I sort Asian countries in column Asia and African countries in column African as well?
How to separate countries name from numbers to Sum it later.
I tried to copy that information from web page and paste it in excel and then read it with pandas but all i got is introduced bellow and couldn't make any operation:
AFRICA                   Unnamed: 1                           Unnamed: 2
0     ALGERIA  5,142      ERITREA  211                        MOZAMBIQUE  7
1        ANGOLA  582       ESWATINI  2                          NAMIBIA  10


The simplest way to do this is to create a function that does the job
import pandas as pd
import re

data_asia = [
    "AFGHANISTAN 5,000",
    "BAHRAIN 8",
    "JORDAN 1,188",
    "KUWAIT 162",
    "SAUDI ARABIA 619"
]

data_africa = [
    "ALGERIA 5,142",
    "ANGOLA 582",
    "ERITREA 211",
    "ESWATINI 2",
    "MOZAMBIQUE 7",
    "NAMIBIA 10"
]

def separate_countries_numbers(data):
    countries = []
    numbers = []
    for item in data:
        split_data = re.split(r'\s(?=\d)', item)
        country = split_data[0]
        number = split_data[1].replace(",", "")  
        countries.append(country)
        numbers.append(int(number))
    return pd.DataFrame({"Country": countries, "Number": numbers})

df_asia = separate_countries_numbers(data_asia)
df_africa = separate_countries_numbers(data_africa)

df_asia, df_africa

which returns
(        Country  Number
 0   AFGHANISTAN    5000
 1       BAHRAIN       8
 2        JORDAN    1188
 3        KUWAIT     162
 4  SAUDI ARABIA     619,
       Country  Number
 0     ALGERIA    5142
 1      ANGOLA     582
 2     ERITREA     211
 3    ESWATINI       2
 4  MOZAMBIQUE       7
 5     NAMIBIA      10)

